# Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals error with mean function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a giant data array where in every row I want to extract specific columns and then average the numbers I extract. This is my code:

```
for i=1:1000
    temp=data(i,:);
    index_data=temp([1,10,11,12,19]); %columns I want to extract
    data_final(i,1)=mean(index_data(~isnan(index_data)));
end
```

I get an error on the first iteration. The array that is extracted is

```
[NaN NaN NaN NaN 15.64]
```

And what I get when I type index_data(~isnan(index_data)) is 15.64, what I'd expect. However, I get an error of

```
??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
Error in ==> mean(index_data(~isnan(index_data)))
```

Calling this from the command line yields the same error. However, if I try with the covariance function (cov) I don't the get the error. This seems really weird to me!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 12):

I suspect that you have defined a variable `mean` with the same name as the built-in function. You can check using:

```
which mean
```

To solve the problem, delete the variable from memory: `clear mean`, then correct all references of this variable...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The error in my case was due to using mean as a variable name, which also happens to be a name of a function.

Since it was a mean, MATLAB considered the keyword **mean** as a variable name but not the function.

I hope my comment helps